# getting Import "flask_wtf" could not be resolved

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am getting 'Import "flask_wtf" could not be resolved'.
I had the same problem with:
from flask import Fask

I Had to reinstall flask multiple times

for flask_wtf
I am getting Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous in c:\users\myprojectvenv\venv\lib\site-packages
...
Installing collected packages: WTForms, flask-wtf
Successfully installed WTForms-3.0.1 flask-wtf-1.1.1

but still nothing is working

I tried reinstalling the flask and flask_wtf

Comment: Remember to include [all the details in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Is this in a virtual environment? plain global installtion? _how_ did you install flask? Are you using `pip`? `poetry`? What is the full error? (and remember: use markdown for anything that's code or logs etc).

Comment: it was in the venv, and yes my I am using pip

Comment: That goes [in your post](/help/how-to-ask). You're not asking a question on SO "for yourself", you're asking it "for everyone who might have this problem" so even if you got an answer, update your post to properly describe the problem so that others can tell whether or not that's the same problem they had.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are in your virtual environment
that is (venv)

check your terminal if the path to your project looks something like this

(venv) c:\users\myprojectvenv\venv\lib........
or something like that

deactivate it

in your terminal run the command "pip install flask-wtf"

then reactivate it using the:
venv\Scripts\activate

this should solve the issue.
I had a similar problem.

Comment: not a problem, good luck coding :)

Comment: That should absolutely not be necessary at all. The _whole point_ of a virtual environment is to contain the dependencies so as not to pollute the system/global python installation. The whole point of virtual environment is that they let you install _anything_ in project scope, including flask. Exiting a venv and installing a package globally is the worst possible solution.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans what is the better solution, if i do not have to deactivate my virtual-environment and still be able to resolve the import issue, your comment makes sense for a professional project, but this is a project from what I can understand, still please share a better solution if possible.

Comment: I will, if they update their post to include all the relevant details, because right now their question is incomplete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).